# Windows OpenSSH sshd: can't get passwordless authentication to work

Tags: windows, passwords, openssh, sshd

I am trying to configure OpenSSH as an ssh server (sshd) on Microsoft Windows 10, as described here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement

The instructions are clear and easy to follow, but after completing them, I am still prompted for a password. My first test just uses ssh to access the same (Windows) computer, although the same problem occurs if I try to ssh into this computer from a different computer. As you can see in the output below, I created two keypairs: one for RSA, and one for Ed25519.

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Administrator/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
...
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'administrator'
...
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa (<redacted>), agent
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519 (<redacted>), agent
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_dsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_xmss (0000000000000000)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
...
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:<redacted> C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Offering public key: ED25519 SHA256:<redacted> C:\\Users\\Administrator/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
...
debug3: remaining preferred: password
```

Get-Service shows that ssh-agent is running.
ssh-add -l shows two entries for this user.

It does correctly accept the user's password, but this effort is a small part of a project that requires automating some steps that run commands on another Windows computer, so I need to use the passwordless auth feature.

(If it helps, I come from the Linux/Unix world, and have configured ssh in those environments.)

Thanks for any help in troubleshooting this!

ACLs of the sshd config file:

```
icacls sshd_config 
   sshd_config NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F) 
   BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F) 
   NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(RX)
```

**Problem solved**: A teammate suggested that the steps in the most upvoted answer here (link below) might help. I only needed step 4 ("Setup permissions properly") and 5 (Comment out 2 lines in sshd_config).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212816/setting-up-openssh-for-windows-using-public-key-authentication

Now it works correctly.

Comment: OpenSSH is unable to open your configuration file.  Does the file exist?  If it does exist what permissions does it have?

Comment: @Ramhound icacls sshd_config
sshd_config NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
            BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
            NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(RX)

Comment: Edit your question and include the formatted information.  At this point I would remove and reinstall the OpenSSH Server to regenerate the default configuration file and get rid of the error in question

Comment: Good that you share your solution. Instead of adding it to the question you should write a separate answer and later accept it. This will mark your question as answered. I suggest to cite the relevant lines of the answer you are referring to. You can directly link to the "most upvoted answer" using the gray `Share` below this answer.

Comment: Thanks @Bodo, will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

OpenSSH is (appropriately, IMO) very picky about permissions on the files that contain keys. The Microsoft documentation that I referenced in the question did not provide the steps to set perm's.

A teammate suggested the answer in another question (link below). Here are those steps, lightly edited.

Setup permissions properly:

1. Run start . to open explorer with the current folder (`$env:USERPROFILE\.ssh`)
2. Right click authorized_keys, go to Properties -> Security -> Advanced
3. Click "Disable inheritance"
4. Choose "Convert inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object" when prompted
5. Remove all permissions on the file except for SYSTEM and yourself. There must be exactly two permission entries on the file. Both SYSTEM and yourself should have full control over the file.

If your Windows build is 1809 or later, you must comment out the following lines in `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config` file. Then restart the sshd service.

```
# Match Group administrators                                
#       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

Original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212816/setting-up-openssh-for-windows-using-public-key-authentication

Comment: Commenting of C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config helped (then restart sshd service) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me on Windows 11.

After changing permissions and the sshd_config file, you also need to restart the service named "OpenSSH SSH Server" in Windows Services.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).